# CorePlot control on pinching

Tags: ios, core-plot

I was wondering if there is way to control the scale of the chart while pinching in a way that when you pinch horizentally the x-axis get scaled and if you pinched vertically y-axis get pinched. this why scattersXY plots which has a lot of spikes and ups and downs (e.g. from 100% to 0% back to 90%) can be fixed by the user to improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plot space delegate to control how the graph responds to user interaction. See the [`< CPTPlotSpaceDelegate >` docs](http://core-plot.github.io/iOS/protocol_c_p_t_plot_space_delegate-p.html) for the available delegate methods.